# How to convert ByteArray string from json file to qimage in visual c++?

Tags: qt, visual-c++

```
json j1 = json::parse(strForJSON);'\\parsing json value'
string  imagesData = j1["key"].dump();'\\key name for arrayvalue in json'
QImage img((const uchar*)imagesData.data(),WIDTH,HEIGHT,QImage::Format_RGB16);'\\creating image'
imshow("window", matImg);'\\show the image'
```

Comment: help me to fix it, this is creating some combination of colours, not an exact image

Comment: would you please show the data in your JSON? what is the encoding? base64? I don't think that JSON can include binary data, so it should be some sort of encoding on it. you may want to attach a JSON sample to your answer

Comment: There is no base64 encoding. There is no other type of encoding and the data is look's like   {"key":[-119,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,3,-24,0,0,3,.....]; }

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

- You are using [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library for JSON stuff
- Data in `v` key is an array of numbers, containing raw data from a PNG image or other image formats supported by QImage

Then, you need to convert the value of `v`, to some STL container first and then convert it to [QByteArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html). Here is my solution:

```
json j1 = json::parse(strForJSON);
std::vector<char> imagesData = j1["v"].get<std::vector<char>>();
QByteArray imagesDataArray(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(imagesData.data()),imagesData.size());
QImage img;
bool loadSuccess = img.loadFromData(imagesDataArray);
```